# In PowerShell, How I do I filter for an object by its nested property key/value object?

Tags: powershell, filtering

An object returned from a get-log command can look like

> ```
> Date: <date>
> Properties: 
>         statusCode     : OK
>         serviceRequestId: 97168d7a-4c92-4d65-b509-65785b14ef42
> Name: <name>
> Details: <details>
> ```

I want to do something that returns that the one object by doing something like

```
get-log | where-object { $_.Properties.serviceRequestId -eq '97168d7a-4c92-4d65-b509-65785b14ef42' }
```

Of course, this does not work, but I want something that works like this.

My goal is to see the "Details" property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The filtering sample you provided works as is:

```
get-log | where-object { $_.Properties.serviceRequestId -eq '97168d7a-4c92-4d65-b509-65785b14ef42' }
```

That will return the object(s) you want (the full object, not just inner properties).

So you can use the result of that to get at any other property, like `Details`:

```
$result = get-log | where-object { $_.Properties.serviceRequestId -eq '97168d7a-4c92-4d65-b509-65785b14ef42' }
$result.Details
```

Or you can do it all in one line by continuing the pipeline and using `Select-Object`:

```
get-log | 
    where-object { 
        $_.Properties.serviceRequestId -eq '97168d7a-4c92-4d65-b509-65785b14ef42' 
    } |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Details
```

(did it on multiple lines for better readability)